# How many numbers less than $x$ have a prime factor that is not $2$ or $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to figure out the number of integers greater than $1$ and less than or equal to $x$ that have a prime factor other than $2$ or $3$.  For example, there are only two such integer less than or equal to $7$.

It is straight forward to determine how many many integers less than or equal to $x$ have a prime factor other than $2$:
$$x - \left\lfloor{\log}_2x\right\rfloor$$

Or to make the same determination about $3$:
$$x - \left\lfloor{\log}_3x\right\rfloor$$

What is the method or formula for figuring out how many integers less than or equal to $x$ have a prime factor other than $2$ or $3$?

I know that it is less than:
$$x - \left\lfloor{\log}_2x\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\log}_3x\right\rfloor$$

and greater than:
$$x - \left\lfloor{\log}_2x\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\log}_3x\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\right\rfloor$$

Thanks,

-Larry

---

Edit:  Added a greater than clause.

Comment: Use the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion (and $\log_6 x$) seems to be a red herring here:  we exclude the powers of $2$, we exclude powers of $3$, and we need to keep excluding the other numbers of the form $2^a 3^b$.

Comment: It's clearly equal to $x-\lfloor \log_2 x\rfloor - \lfloor \log_2 \frac{x}3 \rfloor - \lfloor \log_2 \frac{x}9 \rfloor-\ldots$. But that answer kind of stinks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $x - \left\lfloor{\log}_2x\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\log}_3x\right\rfloor +  \left\lfloor{\log}_6x\right\rfloor$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hardy's book
of Twelve Lectures on Ramanujan's work,
in the chapter
"A lattice point problem",
he discusses Ramanujan's result that

"the number of numbers 
of the form
$2^x 3^y$
less than $n$
is

$\dfrac{\log(2n) \log(3n)}{2 \log 2 \log 3}
$"

There is a very extended discussion
of this problem.
Among the results is a proof
that the error in
Ramanujan's formula
is
$O(\frac{n}{\log n})$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $n - A(n)$ where $A(n)$ is the number of integers $\le n$ of the form $2^x 3^y$.  Now $A(n)$ is the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $x \log 2 + y \log 3 \le \log n$, i.e. the number of lattice
points in the triangle $x \log 2 + y \log 3 \le \log n$, $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$.
This is within $O(\log n)$ of the area of the triangle, i.e. $\log(n)^2/(2 \log(2)\log(3))$.  But I doubt you'll get a "closed form" for the exact value.

EDIT: See also [OEIS sequence A071521](http://oeis.org/A071521) and references there.

Comment: I was thinking this too; I believe [Baker's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) is relevant to finding better approximations (and maybe a closed form), since it lets you bound quantities like $x\log(2)+y\log(3)$ and I've seen papers where people somehow use it to get explicit, numeric bounds. You wouldn't happen to know how such tricks are done, and if they might be applicable here, would you?

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  Wow.  Some great topics to read up on.

Comment: I don't immediately see the relevance of Baker's theorem here.  $\log(n) - x \log(2) - y \log(3)$ for **nonnegative integers** $x, y, n$ can be $0$ (if $n = 2^x 3^y$), or if positive it's at least $\log(n/(n-1))$ (with equality if $n = 2^x 3^y + 1$).