# Looking for methods for approximating an iterative equation regarding primes

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, approximation-theory

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1070056/48606), I was looking for an equation for counting the number of the number of integers between $1$ and $x$ that have a prime factor besides $2$ or $3$.

There were 2 iterative equations that came up:

- $x−\left\lfloor{log_2x}\right\rfloor−\left\lfloor{log_2\frac{x}{3}}\right\rfloor−\left\lfloor{log_2\frac{x}{9}}\right\rfloor− \dots$
- $x - \left\lfloor{log_2x}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{log_3x}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{x}{6}}\right\rfloor + $ count integers in [$1,\frac{x}{6}$] with factor other than $2$ or $3$

There were two answers that involved interesting approximations:

- $\dfrac{\log(2n) \log(3n)}{2 \log 2 \log 3}$ with error $O(\frac{n}{\log n})$
- $\dfrac{\log(n)^2}{2 \log(2)\log(3)}$ with error $O(\log n)$

Are there any standard methods for getting from the iterative equations above to the approximation equations below?  If not, would anyone be able to show an approach to be able to approximating either of the equations above with an error estimate?

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: Since the number of numbers of the form $2^a3^b$ plays a role, you can look at wikipedia, smooth numbers (in this case $3$-smooth). A number is $k$-smooth, if every prime factor of it is $\le k$.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I'll take a look at the wikipedia article on smooth numbers for details on approximating the total number less than a given integer $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Peter's help above, I was able to answer my question using the Wikipedia article on [smooth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).

The best way to proceed on this is to recognize that the { number of integers $\le x$ with factor other than $2$ or $3$ } = $x$ - { the number of $3$-smooth numbers $\le x$ }

The number of 3-smooth numbers can be approximated using:

$$\Psi(x,3) = x \cdot \rho(u) + O(\frac{x}{log{\,3}}) $$

where $u = \dfrac{\log x}{\log 3}$

and

$\rho(u)$ is the [Dickman function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function)

and

$\Psi(x,y)$ denotes the number of $y$-smooth integers less than or equal to $x$

Comment: I know that's incredibly too late for such a comment (I've just observed it looking at some archival posts on Dickman function) but $O(x / log 3)$ is the same as $O(x)$, and $x*\rho(u)$ is also $O(x)$. So actually we obtain here nothing more than that $\psi(x,3)$ is at most linear in $x$. But it's bounded by $x$ anyway, so it's not helpful.

In general, Dickman function might be useful if u stays around some constant, but it's rather useless when u is going to infinity.

(If commenting on old posts is not acceptable, please ban me. I just couldn't stand not working answer)

Comment: (something like $\frac{1}{2} \log_3(n) \log_2(n)$ should work by the way)